# having problems with axios API call. the response change randomly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post

so I'm trying to post data to the server and get a response in return.
somehow the API response change randomly Idk why, maybe you guys have any clue...

this is my code -

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState({
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  userName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
});
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
axios
  .post("/register", {
    fullname: data.firstName + " " + data.lastName,
    username: data.userName,
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    setMessage(res.data.success);
    console.log(message);
    if (message) {
      console.log("success");
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
};

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setMessage(false);
  setErrorMessage(false);
  const newData = { ...data };
  newData[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
  setData(newData);
};
```

I have no clue what is causing this issue...

[image]

so the first time I get false, and then all the other calls are true, although I have a unique property for this property in my schema.
sometimes it starts with false and then true and then all false.

second scenario

[image]

any idea guys?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `console.log(message);` is showing you the *current* state, which is: `const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);`  There's no error, just an incorrect expectation of state updates.

Comment: thank you guys for your help, so david any idea how i should change it?

Comment: Sure, the value you want at that time is in `res.data.success`, not `message`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your code, the variable *message* is boolean.
Basically, the *setMessage()* effect is not immediate but it is delayed. In order to overcome the problem you have to use *useEffect()* to capture the change.

You can do something like this:

```
axios
    .post("/register", {
        fullname: data.firstName + " " + data.lastName,
        username: data.userName,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setMessage(res.data.success);
    });

useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
        console.log("success");
    } else {
        console.log("error");
    }
}, [message])
```